# 404 errors, pages getting a url repeated?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get rid of my 404 errors. An example of this is the following link:  http://www.transitiongraphics.co.uk/dbmax/www.transitiongraphics.co.uk. On investigating, the error says its coming from    http://www.transitiongraphics.co.uk/dbmax/. I have checked the page and can not find this link anywhere. This is a SVG media file, I have also check the code of the SVG and there are no embedded links.

Pretty much all my 404 errors are because the links have an additional /www.transitiongraphics.co.uk added to the end of the url. What could be possibly adding this?

I should probably mention this is a WordPress site.

If I just redirected these links back to there proper url, would that cause more issues? I would preferably like to find the source of the issue though, rather then working around it.

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress.

Comment: Did you put the link without a protocol ( `www.example.com` vs. `http://www.example.com` ) >??

Comment: I did yes, does not seem to make a diffrence?